# OpenCV Attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'SVM_RBF'

Tags: python, opencv

I just started using OpenCV 3.0 in python. I am trying one of the example "didgits.py" and I am getting the Attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Jindal\Desktop\opencv\sources\samples\python2\digits.py", line 171, in <module>
    model = KNearest(k=4)
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Jindal\Desktop\opencv\sources\samples\python2\digits.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.model = cv2.KNearest()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KNearest'
```

Then I commented the code for `KNearest` and tried for `SVM` only and again I got the Attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Jindal\Desktop\opencv\sources\samples\python2\digits.py", line 177, in <module>
    model = SVM(C=2.67, gamma=5.383)
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Jindal\Desktop\opencv\sources\samples\python2\digits.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.SVM_RBF,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SVM_RBF'
```

I tried to search for these variable in OpenCV but couldn't find anything.

Are the python examples not updated? Where can I find the complete list of python API's and reference manual for OpenCV3.0 python, as the online [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) is not complete for Machine Learning because I found many python API mentioned in 2.4.9 but not in 3.0?

Comment: just show your code !

Comment: @Kasra:  He said he's trying one of the examples that came with it.  *His* code would be [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/digits.py)

Comment: i can find cv2.ml.SVM_RBF, but no way to construct an SVM in 3.0 now.

Comment: @Gerrat: yes that's the example I'm trying.

Comment: @berak: So this means that the examples are not updated and I can not perform SVM in 3.0, right?

Comment: @Arpit, can't really answer this now, i need a bit more research here. again, 3.0 is *very* alpha atm, and the ml module especially problematic (those additionally introduced namespaces broke most of the wrappers.) again, proper issues/bugs should go [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues)

Comment: @Arpit, as long as ml::SVM::create is not wrapped via CV_EXPORTS, there is no way to create one from python/java/matlab.

Comment: @berak: Thanks for the information. I have started working with OpenCV 2.4.9. I guess its better to wait for the stable version.